# Failed to setup Postgresql in Django in namecheap

Tags: django, database, postgresql, installation, namecheap

```
  connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/hatelsln/virtualenv/myunion/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "::1", user "hatelsln_hatelsln", database "hatelsln_myunion", SSL off
```

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/GVcGB.png]

Answer (score 2):

It says it is trying to connect to "::1" which is the IPv6 version of "localhost".

You may want to try "127.0.0.1" as the host to connect to (which may well have access) or the path to the unix socket on the host, which is usually something like "/var/run/postgresql/" (check postgresql.conf if you aren't sure).

Alternatively, if you meant to connect to the IPv6 localhost update your PostgreSQL's pg_hba.conf to allow access.

Comment: Changing "localhost" with "127.0.0.1" worked for me.